# Prepare and execute statements with ActiveRecord using PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, insert, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert values via a prepared statement using ActiveRecord. However, everytime I try:

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
conn.prepare "SELECT * from sampletable where id = $1"
conn.execute 3
```

After the second statement, I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `prepare' for
#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x000001027442c8>
```

What should I do? I'm running Rails 3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.2

UPDATE:

I solved the problem. Thanks for the response, but it didn't work for PostgreSQL. The way to do it is:

```
stmt = "SELECT * from sampletable where id = $1 and name = $2"
values = [ { value: 1}, { value: "henry" } ]
```

where values is an array of hashes, each specifying a value, $1 is bound to the 0th hash, $2 is bound to the 2nd hash in the array and so on

```
con = PG::Connection.new(:dbname => "development_DB")
con.prepare("insert", stmt)
con.exec_prepared("insert", values)
con.close()
```

And this, ladies and gentlemen, works!

Comment: If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copying the answer from the edited question body, in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> I solved the problem. Thanks for the response, but it didn't work for
>   PostgreSQL. The way to do it is:
>
> ```
> stmt = "SELECT * from sampletable where id = $1 and name = $2"
> values = [ { value: 1}, { value: "henry" } ]
> ```
>
> where values is an array of hashes, each specifying a value, $1 is
>   bound to the 0th hash, $2 is bound to the 2nd hash in the array and so
>   on
>
> ```
> con = PG::Connection.new(:dbname => "development_DB")
> con.prepare("insert", stmt)
> con.exec_prepared("insert", values)
> con.close()
> ```
>
> And this, ladies and gentlemen, works!

~ answer per [alalani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1523610/alalani)

Comment: Rather than recreating a new db connection (`con = PG::Connection.new(:dbname => "development_DB")`), I think it would be better to get any existing connection from your adapter, like so: `con = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection`
But otherwise, it works great!